# Optimized storage for large integer series

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I'm currently designing the back-end of a start-up from scratch. We scrape time series from the Internet. We scrape a large amount of integers every minute and store them in rows with a timestamp in csv files.

We didn't start to exploit the data properly as we are still on the design phase. I was wondering, what would be the optimal storage for several years of integer series ? We started to look toward loading it in Postgres, but is sql suited for exploiting time series ?

I was expecting to find a miracle software that would be optimal for handling this kind of specific datasets, and would be glad to hear any suggestion that would enable :

- Persistent large storage
- Averaging/grouping calculation, possibly other R-like features
- Gain in performance, power or ease of use compared to raw sql database storage

Comment: Stack Overflow specific excludes questions regarding software recommendations.  I am going to interpret this question as how to deal specifically with time series in Postgres.  As such, can you provide a little more background on what "large amount of integers" means, on whether you are working with regular or irregular time series, and more information on the type of averaging you might want.  "R" is one of the most powerful statistical packages out there, and it does a lot.

Comment: *Mostly regular, but it can't be assumed as there is data holes and we may have to resample. Currently one of the exploits is making average level hour by hour in a week, for example.
I don't look for specific software recommendation, it's more about asking whether or not it exists as opensource.

Comment: There isn't much info about the data itself because it's really dumb. Every minute, about 8000 integers flows in, that's all there is to it.

Comment: Sorted flat files with fixed-length fields are the most efficient storage for your problem. I'd expect a postgres table to be 4 times larger plus the index on the time column. I'd use the db for much smaller pre-aggregated results and write ad-hoc code to deal with the flat files. I assume that once acquired, your data is read-only forever.

Comment: I'd try to pack it into integer arrays to some degree, as PostgreSQL's huge per-row overhead makes one-value-per-row completely prohibitive. You'll also need to heavily batch your inserts.

Answer (score 3):

Every minute, 8,000 values translates into 11.5 million values per day or 4 billion rows per year.  This is a heavy load.  Just the insert load (using whatever ACID-compliant method) is noticeable -- over 100 inserts per second.  This is definitely manageable in modern database systems, but it is not trivial.

It is quite likely that Postgres can handle this load, with appropriate indexes and partitioning schemes.  The exact nature of this solution depends on the queries that you need to run, but Postgres does have the underlying tools to support it.

However, your requirements are (in my opinion) bigger than Stack Overflow can provide.  If you are designing such a system, you should enlist the help of a professional Postgres DBA.  I might add that you could consider looking at cloud-based solutions such as Amazon Redshift or Microsoft Azure because these allow you to easily scale the system "just" by paying more money.

Comment: We do not have real-time requirements on the output, which is why the task is currently handlded by loading everything in a beast, waiting for a while, get results. But clearly it's not very professional way of working, and the insert load is an issue we are aware of